# How to transfer surface roughness from the unit mm into Strickler coefficient m1/3 per second

Tags: hydrology, models

I have a hydrodynamic model to simulate flash floods. This model expects roughness data in the Strickler coefficient format (kst) in the unit m<sup>1/3</sup> per second.

I got a table with roughness values I'm supposed to use. However the values in the table are in the format mm.

I checked for kst tables online but found different values for the same surface or value ranges like 10 - 15 or highly specific values like "high grass, low grass, pasture". But in the table I got there is just one value for 'grass'. Thus, I would like to use the table I got.

My question is, how do I transfer the roughness values from mm to m<sup>1/3</sup> per second?

Comment: What do you mean with mm? millimeters? then you are good to go, just find the definition of high/low grass (I do not know ... if >100 mm then this is high grass, otherwise low?).